# Group list according to date with multiple dates per item

Tags: c#, android, linq, group-by, xamarin.android

I have a list like follows :-

**List**

**EDIT** (Years can be different fot Birthdays and anniversaries)

```
- EmpGuid -265d317b-b819-4171-ba12-e64388746d81
Name - abc
Birthday - 15 Aug 2000
Anniversary- 12 july 1989

EmpGuid - 265d317b-b819-4171-ba12-e64388746d82
Name - xyz
Birthday - 24 Jan 2000
Anniversary- 15 Aug 1988

EmpGuid - 265d317b-b819-4171-ba12-e64388746d83
Name - mno
Birthday - 15 aug 2000
Anniversary- 24 Jan 1987
```

And I want to group the list according to the dates like so :-

```
12 July - abc anniversary

15 aug - abc Birthday
         mno Birthday
         xyz Anniversary

24 jan - xyz birthday
         mno anniversary
```

I tried doing this :-

```
 var groupedEmpList = FinalList.GroupBy(u => u.Birthdate)
                                      .Select(grp =>new { GroupID =grp.Key, FinalList = grp.ToList()})
                                      .ToList()
```

The the above does not give me the desired output. Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses `SelectMany` to get a flattened list of all the dates on which you can group by the items:

```
var result = FinalList.Select(item => new 
                      { 
                          Date = new [] { item.Birthday.ToString("ddMM"), item.Anniversary.ToString("ddMM") }, 
                          Item = item 
                      })
                      .SelectMany(item => item.Date.Select(date => new { Date = date, Item = item.Item }))
                      .GroupBy(item => item.Date)
                      .Select(grouping => new { Date = grouping.Key, Events = grouping.ToList() }).ToList();
```

*One can also perform the first `select` within the `SelectMany` - for the purpose of the answer I kept it separately*

---

For adding the type of the event (and on the way removing the first `select`):

```
var result = FinalList.SelectMany(item => new List<dynamic>
                        {
                            new { Date = item.Birthday.ToString("ddMM"), Event = "Birthday", Item = item },
                            new { Date = item.Anniversary.ToString("ddMM"), Event = "Anniversary", Item = item }
                        })
                      .GroupBy(item => item.Date)
                      .Select(grouping => new { Date = grouping.Key, Events = grouping.ToList() }).ToList();
```

---

For outputing these results you can:

```
public enum EventTypes
{
    Birthday,
    Anniversary
}

public class Event
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public EventTypes Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Items { get; set; }
}

var result = FinalList.SelectMany(item => new List<dynamic>
                        {
                            new { Date = item.Birthday.ToString("ddMM"), Type = EventTypes.Birthday, Item = item },
                            new { Date = item.Anniversary.ToString("ddMM"), Type = EventTypes.Anniversary, Item = item }
                        })
                      .GroupBy(item => new { item.Date, item.Type })
                      .Select(grouping => new Event { Date = grouping.Key.Date, Type = grouping.Key.Type, Items = grouping.ToList() }).ToList();
```

*Now the `result` list is `List<Event>` and inside you have also your oridinal objects in the `Items` (replace the `dynamic` of that list to your original class type - I just don't know it)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give it a try

Comment: @helloWorld - check  my edit to cope with your need of grouping only by day and month

Comment: I have tried your solution. somehow there seems to be an error in the syntax which Im not able to figure out. Not sure if its the parenthesis. Can you help me with it

Comment: @helloworld - Ok now should be fine

Comment: Thanks this worked fine. Is there a way I can specify the event type? Sorry for being a noob

Comment: @helloworld - What do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121019/discussion-between-hello-world-and-gilad-green).

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to duplicate items (to put same item into up to 2 groups based on different dates) you need to perform that step separately as LINQ does not duplicate items with basic commands.

Simple option - just have 2 lists combined first - one for birthdays and one for anniversary and extract date with its type to wrapping type similar to:

```
 var mergedList = 
      FinalList.Select(x => new { 
          Date = x.Birthdate, Type = "Birthday", Value = x})
      .Concat(
          FinalList
             .Where(x => x.Birthday != x.Anniversary) // if needed
             .Select(x => new { 
                Date = x.Anniversary, Type = "Anniversary", Value = x});

 // Now list have all unique dates - can group and extract any info
 var grouped = mergedList 
    .GroupBy(u => u.Date)
     .Select(grp => new { 
         Date = grp.Key, 
         ListOfNames = grp.Select(x => new {x.Value.Name, x.Type}).ToList()
      })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. ill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a class:

```
class Info
{
    public Guid EmpGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public DateTime Anniversary { get; set; }
}
```

You need to unpivot your class into the following class:

```
class UnpivotInfo
{
    public Guid EmpGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

where your Type is either "Birthday" or "Anniversary", by doing this:

```
var unpivoted = list.SelectMany(i => new[]
{
    new UnpivotInfo {EmpGuid = i.EmpGuid, Date = i.Birthday, Type = "Birthday", Name = i.Name}
    , new UnpivotInfo {EmpGuid = i.EmpGuid, Date = i.Anniversary, Type = "Anniversary", Name = i.Name}
});
```

You can then group your data by date:

```
var groups = unpivoted.GroupBy(p => p.Date);
```

Comment: I tried this and gives me groups according to dates. But the issue is though the month and day can be same, the years can be different for the birthdays and anniversaries (P.S my edit). When I use your answer different groups are created for all the dates as the years are different

Comment: I got it filtered like so :- var groups = unpivoted.GroupBy(p => new { Day = p.Date.Day, Month = p.Date.Month });

Comment: I need it to be a list. Is there a way I can do it?